# How to run any exe with administrator privileges?

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, exe, windows

I am using **makecert** to create certificate i need to do it though c# program the command doesnot execute as it requires administrator privileges.

Please suggest me how to run **any exe using administrator** privileges in windows 7?
If possible than just suggest me the sample code.

Does th o.s. really matters in my case?

Comment: What is it that you're dying to do with elevated privileges?

Comment: @BoltClock i thought that privileges were important in my case as i need admin rights to access the exe . removed privileges

Comment: Why this downvoted and even twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another hint again is using UAC( User Account Control) from the code. Very interestimg source IMHO is this one http://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RunAs:
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true and select an account with the required permissions.

Comment: +1 for `runas` and not falling down the how to program your way out of this hole.

Comment: @morten i tried it using runas but the problem is if i keep the process.useshellexecute=false than it doesnot run as admin, but if i keep it true than it runs well but cant give command to it.It gets deadlock here!!

Comment: deadlock makes no sense. Can you explain more

Answer (score 2):

Use the `runas` verb when starting the process:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(path) { Verb = "runas" };
Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

This assumes that you are running as a user in the administrator group. In that case the UAC dialog will be shown when the process starts.

Answer (score 1):

Change the manifest of the C# application so that it requires adminstrator privileges. UAC should do the rest to prompt the user and elevate the process.